# How to display the value of a HashMap key when user clicks autocom

Tags: java, android, hashmap, autocompletetextview

I'm new to `android` development and `Java` programming. In my code (shown below), when the user `clicks` the `search` `button`, the `value` of a `key` is displayed in `displayField TextView`. But I want it so that the `value` is displayed when the user clicks (touches) an item on the  `AutoCompleteTextView` dropdown items, without needing to `click` the `search` `button`.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{   

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private EditText autocomplete_searchField;
    private TextView displayField;
    String note;

    @Override
    protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    autocomplete_searchField = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_searchField);

    // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_searchField);

    // Gets the string array
    String[] music_note = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.music_notes_array);

    // Creates the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, musicNote);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    displayField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayField);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button); // I want to completely remove this button eventually
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String note = autocomplete_searchField.getText().toString();
            displayField.setText(map.get(note));


    map.put("Doe", "a deer, a female deer");
    map.put("Ray", "a drop of golden sun");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't understand why you needed `autocomplete_searchField` in your code, anyway, if I understood well you just need to remove `button.setOnClickListener` and add the following code:

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

        displayField.setText(map.get(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()));

    }

});
```

Comment: Worked a treat! I'm grateful.

Comment: I'm glad for helping you :)

Comment: The only problem now is that the clicked drop-down item does not respond on the first click (this only happens once, when the app is launched), I have to re-type the word and click the item before it displays the value. Any suggestions as to how to resolve this? Most of the solutions I've seen treat buttons, but not AutoCompleteTextView drop-down items.

Comment: Sorry but I did't understand what you mean. Can you show me your code or an image from the issue?

Comment: I've had to create it as a different question since its not exactly related to the topic of this particular question. Please find question in the following link and assist.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763879/clicked-drop-down-item-in-autocompletetextview-does-not-respond-on-the-first-cli

Answer (score 1):

You need to set ItemClickedListener to AutoCompleteTextView.

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        String note = autocomplete_searchField.getText().toString();
        displayField.setText(map.get(note));
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I replace the button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() method with setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()method?